# After 3 years I posted an up-to-date answer and got some bad feedback — What should I do?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, voting

We are talking about this question:

> [How to schedule airplane mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/242748/87092)

- `Jun 15, 2016` — I asked the question how to schedule the Airplane Mode on my iPhone.
- Got answer mentioning it was not possible
- Marked it as correct
- `Sep 30, 2019` — I updated my iOS version and discovered the Shortcuts app and set up two automations: to enable the Airplane Mode in the evening and to disable it in the morning.
- Posted an answer on my own question and marked it correct (unmarking the previous answer that was saying that was not possible)

The author of the other answer was not very happy and commented:

> [image]

I got some upvotes and a downvote without any explanation... however their answer continues to get upvotes.

I am not sure if I am missing anything here, but I would like to know what I've done wrong.

- Should I have been telling the author to update their answer instead of me posting a new answer?
- Should I have been proposing an edit to the the answer by myself?
- What other options are there?

Comment: Just to avoid grudges, When I said votes are ours, I referred to the DV it already had.

Comment: We had another question about scheduling DND twice etc., it specifically mentioned using shortcuts app etc. natively, in settings, it is not possible.

Comment: @ankii But now there is a thing called Automations.

Comment: your actions were perfectly valid. Posting your own answer is normal. Marking as correct is normal. The person complaining was their issue not yours. Ignore them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for bringing your question here to discuss.

As I commented on your question (done after your screenshot above), it wasn't that I "wasn't very happy", it's that the answer you added and marked as correct didn't appear to answer your own question.

Since your question was asked, you've been able to use Workflow/Shortcuts to set timers to make temporary changes to system settings. It wasn't clear from your question that you were open to this solution.  My understanding was that you wanted to "schedule Airplane mode" and doing this in Airplane mode is still not possible.  Thus, I was confused as to why, suddenly, this had changed because your question was not edited to reflect that change.  I could've worded my comment better so I accept ownership of writing that poorly.

I have since deleted my comments as I realized they were not constructive to getting you the best answer.